# iOS change Keyboard type to Twitter when the user taps the '123' keyboard button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

I have a UITextView but i do not want the keyboard to provide the user with the 'return' key. So in my xib file i set the keyboard type to UIKeyboardTypeTwitter which basically replaces the 'return' key with the '@' and '#'.

However when tapping the '123' button on the keyboard and thus moving into UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation mode, the 'return' key shows up in the bottom right hand side. Is there a way to detect when the user taps on the '123' and then at that time, keep the '@' and '#' symbols in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t have enough control over the keyboard for that (and might not even have as much as you think with the UIKeyboardTypeTwitter approach, if the user has a third-party keyboard that works with that); your best option is to detect when they’ve hit Return (via the UITextViewDelegate method [`-textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)) and blocking the newline insertion that way.

Comment: Yeah if you set the keyboard type to be twitter those 2 symbols replace the 'return' key and everything works fine. Its just that theres no way to detect when you've switched modes. Also if you do tap the '123' button i put a little code in shouldChangeTextInRange to replace the returnKeyType to twitter but when running it displays the button as 'Done' and when tapping that, takes you back to default keyboard type and thus leaving the NumbersandPunctuation mode. I guess it never occurred to Apple that someone might want to have more control over this button. Not cool Apple.. not cool

Comment: by the way, go to twitter and try a tweet. the keyboard is obviously is in twitter mode. now tap the '123' button on the keyboard. You can return to your hearts content - haha. same problem.

Comment: I have an issue capturing the return key - if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]){
       return NO;
    }

This works but if i type in a new character then hit return it takes me back to the default keyboard - away from the number/punctuation keyboard type....not sure why thats happening.

Comment: Yeah if you go into UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation and tap the return key, it returns, like goes to the next line. If you type a character then hit the return key in this mode - it takes you back to the default keyboard type.. thats really weird and not consistent -

Comment: ill go ahead and make this another post i think since its unrelated - thanks for the help